# converting the code to stream (would it make sense? worth the effort?)

Tags: java

I would like to know your opinion on converting the following code to streams instead of using the loop i have.
And could you help me with it, as i am not sure how to combine the multiple loops that i have.
Is it worth the effort and does it make sense?

```
public MyObj determineMyObjForData(String data) {
        List<MyObj> myObjs = myRepository.findAll();
        List<String> splitData = Arrays.stream(data.split(BLANK_SPACE_STRING))
                .map(String::toLowerCase)
                .toList();
        MyObj result = null;
        double highestMatchScore = 0;
        for (MyObj obj : myObjs) {
            List<String> keywords = obj.getKeywords().stream()
                    .map(String::toLowerCase)
                    .toList();
            long hits = keywords.stream()
                    .filter(splitData::contains)
                    .count();
            double currentScore = hits / (double) splitData.size();
            if (currentScore > highestMatchScore) {
                highestMatchScore = currentScore;
                result = obj;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to convert this loop to a stream. You just need some intermediate object to hold the object and its' score. Record is perfect for this job:

```
public record MyObjWrapper(MyObj myObj, double score) {
}
```

Now calculate the score and [map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) each object and score to the wrapper, find the [max](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#max-java.util.Comparator-) element by providing appropriate comparator and extract `MyObj` from the wrapper.

```
public MyObj determineMyObjForDataStream(String data) {
  List<MyObj> myObjs = myRepository.findAll();
  List<String> splitData = Arrays.stream(data.split(BLANK_SPACE_STRING))
          .map(String::toLowerCase)
          .toList();
  return myObjs.stream()
          .map(obj -> {
            long hits = obj.keywords().stream()
                    .map(String::toLowerCase)
                    .filter(splitData::contains)
                    .count();
            double currentScore = hits / (double) splitData.size();
            return new MyObjWrapper(obj, currentScore);
          })
          .max(Comparator.comparing(MyObjWrapper::score))
          .map(MyObjWrapper::myObj)
          .orElse(null);
}
```

Additionally, i would change `splitData` to a `Set` (contains is more efficient for set), unless you have a reason not to use set (maybe you need those duplicates when getting the size?).

Comment: ahh, yes, i'll use set here instead for splitData.